# Custom Attribute above a controller function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

I want to put `[FirstTime]` attribute above a controller function and then create a `FirstTimeAttribute` that has some logic that checks whether the user has entered his name, and redirects him to `/Home/FirstTime` if he hasn't.

So Instead of doing:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Some major logic here
    if (...)
        return RedirectToAction("FirstTime", "Home");

    return View();
}
```

I would just do:

```
[FirstTime]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure. Do something like

```
public class FirstTimeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
        {
          var user = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["User"] as User;
          if(user != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
              filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/home/firstname");
          else
          {
              //what ever you want, or nothing at all
          }
         }
    }
}
```

And just use ***[FirstTime]*** attribute on your actions

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Worked like a charm after you added `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(...);` ... thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry for not adding that in the first place; slipped my mind (working on something else)

Answer (score 0):

Attribute code:

```
  public class FirstTimeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterContext.HttpContext.Request[name]))
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("Default", new RouteValueDictionary
                                            {
                                                { "controller", "Home" },
                                                { "action", "FirstTime" },
                                                { "area", string.Empty }
                                            });
                }
            }
   }
```

Usage:

```
[FirstTime]
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Implementing IActionFilter is redundant. ActionFilterAttribute already implements this interface, and your FirstTimeAttribute inherits from ActionFilterAttribute :)