# Capture User last request timestamp in ASP NET Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for a good place in the ASP.NET Web API lifecycle To update a property in my User entity that is purposed to store the date and time the User last made a request. Obviously, I could just add the code to each of my Controller methods but I would prefer doing this in one place outside of my controllers.

Ideally I would have access to the User principal and could use its Identity property to get the user's ID so that I could retrieve and update my User entity using Entity Framework.

I am currently looking at using a DelegatingHandler implementation.

Can anyone suggest the place in the lifecycle where I should carry this out? A code example would be appreciated.

Comment: You could start with [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't I have to add the ActionFilter to each and every controller method?

Comment: Next, add this to a base controller which you inherit where the function is needed.

Comment: That is a good idea too @Jasen.

Comment: Combined the solutions suggested by CodingYoshi and Jasen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an ActionFilter:

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        // Do your work
    }
}
```

> Yes, but wouldn't I have to add the ActionFilter to each and every controller method?

No, you can apply it to the controller or to actions.

Alternatively, you can do the following and you will not have to apply it to every controller (sort of like a global filter):

```
[LogActionFilter ]
public class LogableApiController : ApiController
{
   ...
}
```

Then inherit that wherever you want.

And lastly, another option is to add to global filters by finding the App_Start/FilterConfig.cs and add:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new LogActionFilter());
}
```

So I have shown you how to apply it to action level, controller level, one or more controllers but not all controllers and then how to apply it to all controllers (global).

Comment: Wait, you just said…

Comment: you can also add it as a global actionfilter if you don't want to add for each controller

Comment: Wait, you just said that I would not have to apply it to every controller but your example shows exactly that. How do I apply it globally.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully: if you want to apply it to some controllers, then use inheritance like I have shown. If you want to apply it to all controllers (globally) then use the last option.

Comment: Thanks @CodingYoshi I'm selecting your answer because it is the most thorough.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an Attribute for your Controller to execute the update on your User Entity with an ActionFilter.
This example explain how to create an attribute for a controller method, it is the same way to do it: [Custom Attribute above a controller function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310112/custom-attribute-above-a-controller-function)

b.e, your controller would be like this:

```
[SaveUserRequest]
public class HomeController : ApiController
```

Comment: Right, I get that that is a possibility but I would have to add this attribute to each and every controller method. I'm looking for something upstream of the Controller.

Comment: you just have to put your attribute on your controller, not on every method